# Dynamic routing nextjs react

Tags: javascript

Help me please.

i am working with next js, i need to make this structure in url sitename/catalog/category/group/product
category, group, product pages are created dynamically, after that I need to generate static pages with ready-filled html markup in the out folder via the 'next export' command. I want to get all category, group, product pages to make a completely static site. In the documentation, I did not find information about a large nesting. Please tell me how to do it. Here is my current structure and what next js generates for me

Is it possible to do this?

my file structure

```
pages
   catalog
      index.tsx
      [category]
         index.tsx
         [group]
            index.tsx
```

Comment: catelog/[category]/[group]/[product]/index.js will be the correct structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dynamic URL using [slug] for all dynamic variable in your URL component.
Check the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Once you use dynamic URL, you need to serve getStaticProps (for data as props) and getStaticPaths (for diff routes) method on page to serve the data.

*Note: above method are only executed on build time, in case of next export also.*